# Proof by induction that *p* = 1/*p*-1 in golden rectangle exercise

Tags: induction, golden-ratio

The initial rectangle's dimensions is L0 for the length and l0 for the width.

A golden rectangle can be obtained when it has the same proportions as the initial rectangle, so *p* = L0/l0

I am first asked to make relations between L*n+1* and l*n*, and then between l*n+1* and, l*n* and L*n*.

I got L*n+1* = l*n* and l*n+1* = L*n* - l*n*

Then I have to prove by induction that *p*= 1/*p*-1 before deducting *p* = 1+sqrt(5)/2

I'm totally stuck for how to prove this, what shall I do?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_n = \dfrac{L_n}{l_n}$. 
Since $L_{n+1} = l_n$ and $l_{n+1} = L_n - l_n$ we have
$$
p_{n+1}
=\dfrac{L_{n+1}}{l_{n+1}}
=\dfrac{l_n}{L_n - l_n}
=\dfrac{l_n}{l_n p_n - l_n}
=\dfrac{l_n}{l_n(p_n - 1)}
=\dfrac{1}{p_{n}-1}
$$
If $p_n$ is always equal to $p$ we get
$$
p = \dfrac{1}{p-1}
$$
as required.